# Attempt to insert non-property value problem in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I've been stuck with this problem for like few good hours and to be honest can't find the solution, I'm trying to store NSDictionary using UserDefaults, but for some reason it crashes in runtime at main method even tho I'm storing NSDictionary which is a legit type for UserDefaults.

Here's my Code:

```
-(void)getEventAlbums
{
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[ELConfig getBaseUrl]];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"album/getAlbums/%@", [self.mEventData valueForKey:@"eventKey"]];
    [manager POST:urlString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        
        _albumsDict = [(NSDictionary *)responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_albumsDict forKey:@"feedAlbums"];
        
        
        
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        
        // failure
        
        NSLog(@"Error retreiving albums");
        
    }];
}
```

btw _albumsDic is type of NSArray.

Comment: Please post a stack trace of the crash

Answer (score 0):

Check all nested data (in all arrays and dictionaries) in that responseObject. Somewhere there is something not of class NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSNumber, NSData or NSDate.
This way as you have used you can store only 100% plist compatible data.

If your classes support NSCoding protocol you can convert your objects to NSData and save that in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you check if you are having a valid property list:

```
- (BOOL)isValidPropertyList:(id)object {
    
    NSData      *xmlData;
    NSError     *error;
    
    xmlData=[NSPropertyListSerialization
        dataWithPropertyList:object
        format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
        options:0
        error:&error
    ];
    
    if(xmlData)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Tested object is not a valid property list: %@",error);
    }
    
    return NO;
}
```

Add to your class, and use like `[self isValidPropertyList:_albumsDict];`